# How do I get the Light Intensity Value at a specific location?

Tags: lumen, lighting, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I'm trying to create a stress mecanic for my horror game on **Unreal Engine 5.2**. The darker the room is, the higher the stress value will increase.

Is it possible to detect the **lighting intensity value at a specific location** ?

I found some solutions talking to this specific problem :

- https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/how-do-i-get-the-light-levels-at-the-players-position/285380

> I really want to add a realistic trait to it, taking the indirect lighting into account. This is why I wanted to use something else than RayTracing.

- [This plugin in the UE marketplace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOwfk.png)

> The source code is not exposed and I can't see how he did it (for obvious reasons).

Do you have any hints ? I'm new to Unreal Engine so I really don't know what the engine actualy allows me to do.